# Why my Qt test (which uses a QProcess) fails?

Tags: c++, qt, ctest

I created a Qt test which invokes another program thanks to a QProcess. After calling the `QProcess::start` method, my test waits for it to finish with the `QProcess::waitForFinished` method. When I run this test with Qt Creator, there's no problem. But when I run it with [CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html), the `QProcess::waitForFinished` function always returns false. Can someone explain me why ? Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code.  Are you specifying the child process’s executable via a relative path?  If so, perhaps CTest has a different current directory and therefore can’t find the executable to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution : the `QProcess:start` method couldn't find the program because the working directory of my Qt test wasn't good. So, I changed it with the `QDir::setCurrent` and now, it works.